# How to test if a variable is contained in a list of integers with Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'd like to do something along the lines of...

```
if current_user.id in?(1,2,3,100,312)
 .....
```

How is this possible with ruby? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby has an include function. The syntax is as follows

```
[1,2,3].include?(2)
```

Answer (score 2):

The keyword you are looking for is [include](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-include-3F). However, it works the opposite way than you have it. It needs to be `ARRAY.include?(WHAT_YOU_ARE_LOOKING_FOR)`

```
if [1,2,3,100,312].include?(current_user.id)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if [1,2,3,100,312].include?(current_user.id)
    ....
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 1):

Everyone's pointed out `Array#include?`. Note that if there's a lot of values in the array, include? can be a relatively expensive O(n) operation. Ruby's Set is O(1) on lookup, so if speed is an issue:

```
require 'set'

SPECIAL_USER_IDS = Set[1,2,3,100,312]
...
if SPECIAL_USER_IDS.include? current_user.id
```

I've initialized the set separately instead of inline as Set.new(array) is itself an O(n) operation. In microbenchmarks, I've found sets are marginally faster even with low cardinality (all the way down to single elements) and significantly faster with high cardinality.